# Caching image to service worker is causing a CORS issue

Tags: firebase-storage

I am getting the following error in my console when trying to cache image from firebase

> access to fetch at 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/110kb.png?alt=media&token=9447ba8f-5165-4b31-9bb6-c710394b2e2d' from origin 'https://app.myapp' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

what is the case here since I am working on a custom caching policy and I don't want to add the images to my static file.

Comment: Can you provide any reproducible steps, so we can be on same page while solving your issue ?